# What is the definition of a tetrad/vielbein?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, reference-frames, terminology, definition

This is hopefully a simple question about definitions.

In mathematics, we have the [tangent frame bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_bundle#Tangent_frame_bundle), which is often just called the frame bundle. Local smooth sections are then called smooth frames, and can be used to define a local basis. As far as I understand, there is no requirement that such frames be orthonormal.

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrad_formalism#Mathematical_formulation) wiki article briefly describes the mathematical formulation of tetrads, and says that they are local sections of the frame bundle. It also mentions that a popular choice of tetrad basis is an orthonormal tetrad basis.

In physics, it seems to be taken as given that a tetrad basis is orthonormal. I believe such a basis is called a frame field.

---

I want to clarify the terminology:

Is a frame field a choice of smooth frame such that the basis is orthogonal (pointwise)?

Is it then the convention that these frame fields are referred to as tetrads in physics, even if there is a more general use of the word tetrad for *any* smooth frame?

Please also point out if you think my definitions are wrong or unconventional in the first place.

Comment: Tetrad (Vierbein in German, generally viel( from "many")bein) is a term in physics, since we mean a 4D (curved) spacetime. "A frame field" is the general mathematical term which, for GR purposes has a particular definition and orthogonality wrt to the "flat Minkowski metric". The latter is chosen for convenience.

Comment: So in mathematics is a frame field a section of the frame bundle (which defines a basis which does not need to be orthogonal), whilst in physics it refers to a section of the frame bundle which defines an orthogonal basis (w.r.t. Minkowski metric)?

Comment: Yes, that is pretty much it.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying for me!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_bundle#Orthonormal_frame_bundle